# Facebook FQL getting all my friends last position update

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get all my friend's last position update with this fql query:

```
SELECT author_uid, message, latitude, longitude, timestamp FROM location_post WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

I would like to take just the latest update for every friend but this query returns me more than one update for a single friend. 
I tried to set a limit at the end of the query (equal to the number of my friends) but it does not work. 
How I should change it?

Answer (score 0):

If it was a normal database, not a facebook FQL, you could use join and get your results in single query. Unfortunately Facebook FQL does not allow joins or even max function.

But you can:

Receive all the friend ids like in your query

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
```

Then for each friend uid run the query

```
SELECT author_uid, message, latitude, longitude, timestamp FROM location_post 
  WHERE author_uid = FRIEND_ID order by timestamp desc limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately Facebook has a "query per minute" limit so if I exceed it I will be blocked for some minutes. Is there any other solution?